# Как заставить браузер не кэшировать данные?

Tags: javascript, кэширование, браузер

Имеется ввиду, программным путем средствами JavaScript'a?
Есть ли некий универсальный метод, который заставит любой из популярных браузеров не кэшировать данные а постоянно брать новые?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Или как то так!

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

Comment: А за что экспайрес отвечает?

Comment: За истечение "срока годности" документа.

Comment: дата истечение срока кеша. тоесть кеш устарел еще вчера - значит его нужно обновить! в принципе можно поставить 0, эффект тот же!

Answer (score 3):

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="NO-CACHE">
```

Как-то так. Но заставить что-либо сделать сложно: слишком они, браузеры, самостоятельные.
Это лишь пожелание.

Comment: Только хотел спросить чем meta теги не устраивают?

Comment: knes, так это же не запрет кеширования. Я слышал что в Википелии ошиблись, те кто такое посоветовал :-))

Comment: Это не запрет, это рекомендация. Запретить вообще ничего нельзя: разработчик вправе закэшировать любую инфу от сервера. Разве что каждый раз менять ссылку на содержимое, но тогда это уже не запрет кэширования, мягко говоря.

Comment: Я понял Вашу мысль... Но все же мне кажется там должен быть другой азголовок:

    header("Cache-control: no-store, max-age=0e");

А `header("Cache-control: no-cache");` это вроде для прокси серверов.